# Connecting multiple SPI devices to Texas Instruments CC3200 LaunchPad

Tags: microcontroller

I want to connect one of the two (or both) 433 MHz RF receiver modules to the Texas Instruments CC3200 LaunchPad:

- [RFM83CL-433S1](http://www.soselectronic.de/a_info/resource/c/RFM83CL-433S.pdf)
- [RFM65CW-433S2](http://www.soselectronic.de/a_info/resource/Hope/RFM65CW.pdf)

I also want to connect an [SD Card connector to the LaunchPad](http://e2e.ti.com/support/wireless_connectivity/f/968/p/380785/1356116.aspx) at the same time. Is this possible? Is it possible to connect all three devices to the CC3200 LaunchPad at the same time and get each of these addressed?

I guess it would require two additional chips, one to change binary format to dedicated lines (green below) and one 4-way AND gate (blue below):

[image: Multi SPI Device Scheme]

Is this assumption correct? Or is there already something similar available on the CC3200 LaunchPad?

Which chips would I require to accomplish the green and blue area?

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you are aware that the receivers you linked are not SPI bus compatible i.e. they produce data that is totally based on what they receive?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Well, at least the RFM65CW needs SPI to control the receiver. I was falsely assuming that the other chip also required SPI. I'm sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace all the logic in both those boxes with a 2-line to 4-line binary decoder chip, such as the 74LS139. The '139 actually gives you two such decoders. A 74LS138 will give you a single 3-line to 8-line decoder.

Answer (score 1):

If you have enough GPIOs on your controller, you can wire them directly to the SS pins of the SPI devices. If your SS pin is active high, you need to add pull-down resistor, if it's active low, you need to add pull-up resistor.

If you have not enough GPIOs to give your SPI devices each a dedicated pin or you want to save some pins, you can use decoder chips.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me on the pull-up/down resistors! I'm quite a newbie and didn't know this was necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all of those chips. Directly connecting 3 outputs to each of the slave's SS line will work. Keep them pulled up, and pull them down when you need to talk to the specific slave.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. Unfortunately I can tag only one reply as answer here. And due to my low rank I cannot up-vote.